# i have a flutter application and i am using firebase when i am trying to save info to firestore it get's stuck

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (25200): #0      _ItemsUploadScreenState.saveInfo (package:sellers_food_app/upload_screens/items_upload_screen.dart:458:26)
E/flutter (25200): #1      _ItemsUploadScreenState.validateUploadForm (package:sellers_food_app/upload_screens/items_upload_screen.dart:413:9)
E/flutter (25200): <asynchronous suspension>
```

when saving it's stuck in a loop and no info is saved to the storage can any one help?

I thought it was the save function or the validation i tried them then an error no app check token found i set it up by adding the dependencies and the code and now it shows..

```
Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead.
Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
```

but I don't think it's the app check

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"